# MinGW make command not found

Tags: c, mingw

when i run the command

make main.c

it says "make" not found

it should compile the code

im using the vs code terminal
and im using Windows 11 with the latest update
and installed mingw from sourceforge if thats important

Comment: Uninstall your MinGW, install [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), use it to install both MinGW (as described in the link) and Make (`pacman -S make`).

Comment: When saying "installed mingw", always include the exact link you used. There's a dozen different flavors of MinGW, and probably more than one of them is hosted on sourceforge.